# Connecting Hyperledger Composer to Fabric: Error trying install composer runtime

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

While following the tutorial on this [link](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/developer-guide.html), I encontered the following error under the section "Deploy to the running Hyperledger Fabric". My Hyperledger Fabric is not running and I do not know why. The error I get is shown below:

```
tom@tom:~/hyperledger/my-network/dist$ composer network deploy -a my-network.bna -p hlfv1 -i PeerAdmin -s randomString
Deploying business network from archive: my-network.bna
Business network definition:
    Identifier: my-network@0.1.6
    Description: My Commodity Trading network

✖ Deploying business network definition. This may take a minute...

Error: Error trying deploy. Error: Error trying install composer runtime. Error: Connect Failed
Command failed
```

When I use `docker ps -a`, no hyperledger containers are shown to have run. Where could I have gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized I needed to install `docker-compose` which deals with running multiple docker containers instead of just using docker client.

For docker-compose installation, I consulted the [manual](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not start your fabric, if you are developing locally. Please look at https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/development-tools.html for the environment setup and the scripts you need to run inorder to have a local fabric.

When you run `docker ps` you should see something like [this docker list of containers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jydO5.png)